# Javascript grabbing URL parameters and appending to all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm using the script below to grab the URL parameters from my index page, now how would I go about adding what I grabbed to any link/page on my website the user goes to next?

I tried adding the append class to an href I already have on the page but nothing still transfers to the next page.

```
<script>
    var qStr = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1);
    if (qStr.indexOf("utm") > -1) {
      $(".append").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var _href = $this.attr("href");
        if (_href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
          $this.attr("href", _href + "&" + qStr);
        } else {
          $this.attr("href", _href + "?" + qStr);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be use [URLSearchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
// modify location url for demo only
history.pushState(null, null, '?id=10&utm_abc=abcd');

const pageParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)

if ([...pageParams.keys()].some(k => k.includes('utm'))) {

  // every `<a>` has a search property
  $('a').prop('search', (i, curr) => {
    const linkParams = new URLSearchParams(curr);
    // loop over all the params in page url and append to link params
    pageParams.forEach((v, k) => linkParams.append(k, v));
    return linkParams
  });
  
}

// log updated href for demo
$('a').each((_, el) => console.log(el.href))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://exaample.com?foo=bar&x=ffff">one - has params</a>
<a href="http://exaample.com">two - no params</a>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just grab the parameters of the first URL, store it using local storage, and then on every other page, just run a `location.replace(window.location + "?" + parameters);` Is there a downside to doing it this way?

Comment: Doing a replace means reloading the page again. Not really sure what the higher level issue is here that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Im just looking for the easiest possible solution to grab the parameters from the first url and append it to the end of every page's url